# Modify tokenizer in ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr, token

In ANTLR, how to make output the tokens one by one following like push "enter" in keyboard that I try to a class named hello.java like this

```
public class Hello{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello World ...");
    }
}
```

Now, it is time to parse the tokens

```
final Antlr3JavaLexer lexer = new Antlr3JavaLexer();
   try {
      lexer.setCharStream(new ANTLRReaderStream(in)); // in is a file 
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

    final CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream();
    tokens.setTokenSource(lexer);
    tokens.LT(10); // force load


    Antlr3JavaParser parser = new Antlr3JavaParser(tokens);
    System.out.println(tokens);
```

it gives me an output like this,

```
publicclassHello{publicstaticvoidmain(Stringarggs[]){System.out.println("Hello World ...");}}
```

How to make an output looked like this

```
public
class
Hello
{
public
static ... untill the end...
```

I've try using Stringbuilder, but it's not working.
Thanks 4 the help..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just printing out tokens, you have to iterate over tokenstream to get back desired result.

Modify your code like this.

```
final Antlr3JavaLexer lexer = new Antlr3JavaLexer();
try {
  lexer.setCharStream(new ANTLRReaderStream(in)); // in is a file 
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

final CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream();
tokens.setTokenSource(lexer);
//tokens.LT(10); // force load - not needed


Antlr3JavaParser parser = new Antlr3JavaParser(tokens);
// Iterate over tokenstream
for (Object tk: tokens.getTokens()) 
{
 CommonToken commontk = (CommonToken) tk;
 if (commontk.getText() != null && commontk.getText().trim().isEmpty() == false) 
   {
    System.out.println(commontk.getText());             
   }
}
```

After this, You will get this result.

```
 public
 class
 Hello
 {
 public
 static ... etc...
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks 4 Mohit Chawda, God Bless you. It help me a lot.

Comment: How to get the output will be thrown to a JtextArea

This is the code :
`
for (Object tk: tokens.getTokens()) 
{
 CommonToken commontk = (CommonToken) tk;
 if (commontk.getText() != null && commontk.getText().trim().isEmpty() == false) 
  {
   System.out.println(commontk.getText());
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(commontk.getText());
   TextArea.setText("\n " + sb.toString());
  }
}`

It just give me the last tokens. Not the all tokens.
Thanks @Mohit Chawda

Comment: You are actually creating new StringBuilder inside for loop. Initialise it once. And also, take out TextArea code also. Set text after for loop. Hope u get the idea.

Comment: Hi Mohit, check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186240/printing-id-in-lexer-token-antlr